# How to access the hbase timpstamp values of a cell from hive table

Tags: hive, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm working on Hortonworks Sandbox 2.1, and I'm facing a problem that was already discussed here one year a go, but I don't know if the problem is solved in our days, so:

I have created an external hive table that points on top of an HBASE table, with some rows which contained multiple values of the cell...

My understanding is that the hive query on HBASE will fetch the latest version from the HBASE for a column.

Is there a way I can fetch all the versions of a cell?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Hive Hbase integration allows only to fetch the latest time stamp. Please see below mentioned [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration).

"There is currently no way to access the HBase timestamp attribute, and queries always access data with the latest timestamp"